# How are contracts affected if some of the work in the contract becomes impossible?

Tags: contract-law

Example 1: Say I'm given a contract to paint a house, and a few days before I am assigned to paint it, the house is hit by lightning and burns down, making my work impossible to complete. Do I still get paid?

Example 2: Say I'm given a single contract to paint two houses. I paint the first house, then lightning strikes the second and it burns down, so I can't paint the second house. Do I still get paid the value of the entire contract?

Comment: See [impossibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossibility) and [quantum meruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_meruit), respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the duty to perform a contract is usually a "strict liability" obligation, the doctrine of [impossibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossibility) or impracticability of performance invalidates contracts that are impracticable to perform for unforeseeable reasons.

> Example 1: Say I'm given a contract to paint a house, and a few days
> before I am assigned to paint it, the house is hit by lightning and
> burns down, making my work impossible to complete. Do I still get
> paid?

The contract is invalidated and you don't get paid for anything more than the fair market value of the work you actually did under a [quantum meruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_meruit) (a.k.a. unjust enrichment a.k.a. restitution) theory.

> Example 2: Say I'm given a single contract to paint two houses. I
> paint the first house, then lightning strikes the second and it burns
> down, so I can't paint the second house. Do I still get paid the value
> of the entire contract?

No. The contract would likely be found to be "[severable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severability)" and the portion related to the second house would be invalidated on the grounds of impossibility. You would only be paid for the work you actually do.

Comment: I added some more examples, where the client is somehow responsible for the work becoming impossible. Does this change things?

Comment: @bennlich Those are other questions.

Comment: Ah, okay. I moved those to a new question: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/100921/how-are-contracts-affected-if-the-client-makes-some-of-the-work-in-the-contract