# How are contracts affected if the client makes some of the work in the contract impossible?

Tags: contract-law

This is a follow-up from [How are contracts affected if some of the work in the contract becomes impossible?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99696/how-are-contracts-affected-if-some-of-the-work-in-the-contract-becomes-impossibl). In these examples, the work becomes impossible because of some voluntary action of the client.

Example 1: Say I'm given a contract to MC an event. We meet and mutually sign the contract two weeks prior to the event. One week prior, the client decides to cancel the event. Do I still get paid?

Example 2: Say I'm given a contract to write a speech and then to perform the speech at an event. We meet and mutually sign the contract two weeks prior to the event. One week prior, after I've both written the speech and rehearsed my performance, the client decides to cancel the event. Do I get paid for the entire contract? Or only a piece of it?

Answer (score 2):

Contracts generally have mutual obligations. In a typical service contract like you've described, there will be an obligation for A to pay B, and an obligation for B to provide a service to A.

Without a clause permitting it, A cannot unilaterally back out of their promise to pay B.

These risks are normally dealt with by including clauses related to cancellation, notice, non-refundable deposits, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### One of the few times Lionel Hutz got the law right

[image: Lionel Hutz]

Well, almost right. If you are willing to take the consequences, you can break a contract, just like you can murder someone if you don't mind spending the rest of your life in jail.

### Cancellation (termination) of a contract is normally covered by the terms of the contract

In a contract for a professional speaker, it would be standard that there would be terms allowing the principal to cancel and stating what part of the fee is payable. A sliding scale is the most common, with less owing the earlier the cancellation is done, perhaps leading to the full fee being payable if cancelled within, say, 24 or 48 hours.

Cancellation under such a term is not a breach of the contract - it is a method defined at the beginning by which the contract can be terminated other than by performance. Or, more accurately, it is an alternate method of performance through different obligations.

### [Repudiation](https://legalvision.com.au/what-is-repudiation-of-a-contract/)

OK, so let's imagine two people who have entered a public speaking contract but are too stupid to realise that there are all sorts of reasons why the event might not take place and, therefore, don't put those contingencies in their contract. Well, sadly, there is no vaccine for stupid; but that leaves us with a legal problem if the principal cancels the event -  or, equivalently, the speaker cancels their appearance.

Either way, no one has breached their contract because the time for performing their obligations has not yet arisen. However, they have indicated that when that time comes, they will not be performing their obligations. This is known a a repudiation of the contract.

The innocent party has a choice when faced with repudiation:

1. Accept the repudiation (i.e. terminate the contract for cause) and claim damages. The contract ends, and the innocent party gets paid everything they are owed under the contract up until the termination, plus damages for the breach.
2. Reject the repudiation (i.e. affirm the contract) and, if the other party refuses to perform their obligations, seek damages.

For the speaker in your scenarios, option 2 is not realistic - the event has been cancelled, and the speaker can't uphold their end of the contract, so they have no choice but to accept the repudiation.

If the contract provided separate amounts for the preparation and delivery of the speech, then the speaker is entitled to that amount in payment for the preparation part they have completed. However, if the contract is silent, the work they have done is part of their damages claim.

The damages for breach of contract restore the innocent party to the position they would have been in if the contract had been completed. That is not necessarily the full fee for the engagement.

To keep things easy, let's assume the contract is with a company that employs professional speakers. The company charges $2,000 for the engagement and pays $1,500 to the speaker. Assume the cancellation happens before the company has engaged the speaker. No losses have been suffered, so the company is entitled to its expected profit from the contract - $2,000 - $1,500 = $500.

The analysis for a self-employed speaker is similar but less clear because of the difficulty in separating out how much is payment for labour and how much is profit.  Such an analysis might include considering the rates paid to employees under employment agreements and taking that as the cost; the exact calculation is likely to be subject to argument.

In addition to the expectation damages, the speaker is entitled to recover any costs already incurred. For example, if non-refundable travel or accommodation expenses had been paid. In addition, if they had invested time, they could claim damages for that.

An innocent party is legally obliged to mitigate the damages, so your speaker should make reasonable efforts to book another speaking engagement.